# How to correct border between 2 polygons in R?

Tags: r, polygon, sp

What algorithm to use to correct (average) the borderline between 2 polygons? All I know is that they have their own borderlines very close to each other. Sometimes they may overlap, otherwise not.

[image]

As in the image it's visible the common line is fatter than outside borders so it's not ok.

I'd require some average line or just common border - make them adjacent. Those differences are very small so averaging is ok.

EDIT

Given `p1` and `p2` as `SpatialPolygons` I tried the following:

```
sf_p1 = sf::st_as_sf(p1)
sf_p2 = sf::st_as_sf(p2)
sf_u = sf::st_union(sf_p1, sf_p2)
d = gDistance(p1, p2)
```

The plot remains the same. `d` takes 3.03 so I guess there's a little gap between them. I'd probably use buffers? But how?

Comment: Often in these cases the easiest solution is to find a version of your dataset where the boundaries *are* overlapping. Failing that you need to build the topology and eliminate the duplicate arcs and then rebuild the polygons. I *think* the spbabel function might be useful here but without your data I can't be sure. Can you share? Also if its only two polygons you could do the topology ops "by hand" by subsetting the polygons....

Comment: I've flagged this as a duplicate with a solution that requires running an external utility which currently isn't implemented as an R package.